# printf giving me incorrect output in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

This is probably a very elementary problem, but I cannot find the answer anywhere, and this is the first time I've had the problem after several weeks of programming in C. In essence, if I write some code looking something like this:

```
int size;
scanf("%d", &size);
printf("size is %d", &size);
```

If I input, say, size = 2, the program will print back out something along the lines of 133692 or a similar number. Why is this? What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Do you know what `&` operator does in the first place?

Comment: ... And not a single answer was accepted!

Comment: @user9000 he is a new user and this is him first question so ... it will take time

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
printf("size is %d", size);
```

`&` gives you the memory location (address) of a variable.

```
printf("size is %d", &size);
```

So, the above will print the memory location(address) of `size`, not the value stored in `size`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
printf("size is %d", size);
```

instead. This prints the value of the `int` object `size`.

But

```
 printf("size is %d", &size);
```

is undefined behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by undefined? It's quite clear that the latter prints the address of size. (and compiler gives a warning)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen `d` conversion specifier requires an `int` argument, passing an argument of type pointer to `int` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: If you wanted to print the pointer value of &size, you'd use %p rather than %d.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the address of `size`, i.e., `&size`.

Just pass a plain `size`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&` in the `printf` statement as `&size` --> prints the address.

```
      printf("size is %d", size);
```

Answer (score 0):

The calling conventions are different in printf, and scanf.

Printf's arguments are typically by value (no &), but scanf has to have pointers. (&)
(You can't put a new value to e.g. 1.0, but you can print it...)