# Printf is returning with wrong numbers inputted from scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I was writing some basic code to learn the printf and scanf functions, however when integer are inputted via the scanf function, the printf function returns with completely different numbers. A similar thing happens when a character is inputted, only the printf function displays a square instead. Is there a problem with the code, or is it something else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char letter;
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Enter any one keyboard character:  ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    printf("Enter any two integers separated by a space:  ");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

    printf("Numbers output %d and %d \n" , &num1, &num2) ;
    printf("letter input %c\n" , &letter) ;
    printf("stored at %p" , &letter) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever any integers or character is inputted,2686680 and 2686676 are displayed in place of the integers and a filled in rectangle is displayed instead of the character.

Any help would be much appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf giving me incorrect output in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432409/printf-giving-me-incorrect-output-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&letter` mean the address of variable `letter` is stored which the printf are correct. You should use just `letter` in printf arguments as,

```
 printf("%d\n", letter); // prints the value stored in letter

 printf("%p\n", &letter); // prints the address where letter is stored in memory
```