# Guessing Game - Can't figure out why it produces a large negative integer

Tags: c

Cheers guys. I am having trouble with this code I produced. It functions everything fine but when it prints the number when I guessed correctly, it prints a number like -3529583 which I don't understand. Shed some light?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int y, iRandomNum1; // Declare the three variables
    y = 0;
    iRandomNum1 = 0;
    srand(time(NULL)); // Randomize function
    iRandomNum1 = rand() % 10; // Randomize and collect 1 to 10 Value

    while (iRandomNum1 != y) {
        printf("Guess a number from 1 to 10\n");
        scanf("%d", &y);
    }
    printf("\nCorrect Guess! Congrats! The answer is %d.\n", &y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're printing the address of `y`, you should be printing the value, simply remove `&` in the print function. Also note, maybe you should start with `y=-1`, as it is now, if your random value is also 0 you will never get to guess.

Comment: `&y);` in `printf`?

Comment: Oh right! Thank you guys so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf giving me incorrect output in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432409/printf-giving-me-incorrect-output-in-c)

Comment: you might also want to add 1 to `iRandomNum1`, to put it in the range [1-10] like you seem to expect. Without that, it's in the range [0-9].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Comment: **" int y, iRandomNum1; // Declare the three variables"**, comments should reflect what you are actually doing :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are display the address of the variable `&y` instead of the variable itself in your `printf` just remove the `&` symbol and it should be ok

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh had the answer before me in comment